# Uncaught Error: No Iron.Layout found so you can't use yield

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Using Meteor 0.9.3 and iron:router 1.0.0-pre2, this error shows on the console even though iron:layout was installed, see below:

```
willems-mini:iron willem$ meteor add iron:router@=1.0.0-pre2
added iron:location at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:dynamic-template at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:router at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:layout at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:middleware-stack at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:url at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:controller at version 1.0.0-pre2
added iron:core at version 1.0.0-pre2

iron:router: Routing specifically designed for Meteor
```

There are no other packages, just the defaults for meteor:

```
willems-mini:iron willem$ meteor list
autopublish      1.0.0  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure         1.0.0  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router      1.0.0-pre2  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform  1.1.1  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
```

I am trying to run a very simple app:

1 javascript file:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('home');
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.home.events({
        'click button': function () {
            console.log('click!');
        }
    });
}
```

and 1 html file:

```
<head>
    <title>iron router test</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> defaultLayout}}
</body>


<template name="defaultLayout">
    <header>
        {{> yield "header"}}
    </header>

    <article>
        {{> yield}}
    </article>

    <footer>
        {{> yield "footer"}}
    </footer>
</template>


<template name="home">
    {{#contentFor "header"}}
        <button>click header</button>
    {{/contentFor}}

    <button>click</button>

    {{#contentFor "footer"}}
        <button>click footer</button>
    {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not how `iron:router` layouts are supposed to work.

Get rid of your explicit inclusion of the layout in the body :

```
{{! this is WRONG, remove the body tag altogether }}
<body>
    {{> defaultLayout}}
</body>
```

The place where your specify the `layoutTemplate` is in the `RouteController` :

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
},{
 layoutTemplate:"defaultLayout" 
});
```

Declaring explicitly your `RouteController`s is usually a nicer design pattern.

`lib/router.js`

```
Router.route("/",{
  // give the route a name so it figures out itself to use :
  // - HomeController
  // - a template name "home"
  name:"home"
});
```

`lib/controllers/lib/default-layout.js`

```
DefaultLayoutController=RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate:"defaultLayout"
});
```

`lib/controllers/home.js`

```
HomeController=DefaultLayoutController.extend({
  //
});
```

Comment: This solved the problem (thanks), however, it leaves me with one other question:
I am a bit surprised to find that clicks that originate from the named yield regions ('header' and 'footer') do not end up as events for the 'home' template. I can only see these click events in the event handler of the 'defaultLayout' template.
Is there a way to get these events noticed in the 'home' template event handler?

Comment: Just found a way to do this:
I used the new iron-router feature to define event handlers on the route controller. This way I can get all 'home' template events in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Well, like your error says you're missing an iron layout.

Could look something like this in your `lib/router.js` or wherever you hold your router code:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
```

And so the respective `<template name="layout">` should be there.