# No such template: `yeild` in `meteor js` error

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When i am running in local system app working but after deploy this **No such template:yeild** came in console and blank page will coming. How can solve plz help me...

Comment: Hi juanpastas after modify and deploy the app bellow error coming     No Iron.Layout found so you can't use yield! @juanpastas

Comment: What package are you using for iron router? It should be `iron:router`. You can add it with `meteor add iron:router`

Comment: Yaa i am also write as above you said @stubailo

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26121261/1197775